# calculating number of weeks in the basis of customized weekend

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, date, weekday

Different organizations might have a different week off.
So, in this case, need to customize the week off. To do it I have tried the
Sql query write in below

```
DECLARE @dayName VARCHAR(9);
SET @dayName = DATEName(DW, GETDATE());

IF(@dayName = 'Friday' OR @dayName = 'Saturday') 
    PRINT 'Weekend';
ELSE
    PRINT 'NOT Weekend';
```

From the above query I can get my specific weekoff.

for example:

if friday or any other day is mentioned as weekend, then from friday to Thursday corresponds to a week and I need to find how many complete weeks are there in a month? Or in a year?

I want to get  number of weeks on the basis of customized weekOff.

Comment: What do you mean customized weekOff? Is customized weekOff pass as a parameter or save in other table?

Comment: can you show some example ?

Comment: So you meen if sunday is mentioned as weekend, then from sunday to Saturday corresponds to a week and you need to find how many complete weeks are there in a month? Or in a year?  Be more specific

Comment: @D-Shih if friday or any other day is mentioned as weekend, then from friday to Thursday corresponds to a week and I need to find how many complete weeks are there in a month? Or in a year? and it will pass as a parameter.

Comment: @SamuelAC I have updated the question. please have a look.

Comment: @Abdullah Al mamun find my solution below.. it works for sql server 2012 and +

Answer (score 2):

first, you need to make calendar full year or full month, so I would use  *cte recursion* to make it.

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0) AS StartOfMonth,
       DATEADD(mm,1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0)) - 1  AS EndOfMonth
UNION ALL
SELECT StartOfMonth +1 , EndOfMonth
FROM CTE 
WHERE StartOfMonth < EndOfMonth
```

there is 7 days in a week, whatever started with any week, then we will saw this a [Gaps and Islands problem](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/), because the week number will repeat from `1`to `7`.

So I would use `CASE WHEN` with DateName`to make your customer week date number, which number starts on`Friday` or depending on your logic.

```
 ;WITH CTE AS (
      SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0) AS StartOfMonth,
             DATEADD(mm,1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0)) - 1  AS EndOfMonth
      UNION ALL
      SELECT StartOfMonth +1 , EndOfMonth
      FROM CTE 
      WHERE StartOfMonth < EndOfMonth
    )
 SELECT *,
          CASE DateName(DW, StartOfMonth)
              WHEN 'Friday' THEN 0
              WHEN 'Saturday' THEN 1
              WHEN 'Sunday' THEN 2
              WHEN 'Monday' THEN 3
              WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN 4
              WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN 5
              WHEN 'Thursday' THEN 6
              WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN 7 
          END grp,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY StartOfMonth) rn
    FROM CTE
```

**[Results]**:

```
|         StartOfMonth |           EndOfMonth | grp | rn |
|----------------------|----------------------|-----|----|
| 2018-09-01T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   1 |  1 |
| 2018-09-02T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   2 |  2 |
| 2018-09-03T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   3 |  3 |
| 2018-09-04T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   4 |  4 |
| 2018-09-05T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   5 |  5 |
| 2018-09-06T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   6 |  6 |
| 2018-09-07T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   0 |  7 |
| 2018-09-08T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   1 |  8 |
| 2018-09-09T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   2 |  9 |
| 2018-09-10T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   3 | 10 |
| 2018-09-11T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   4 | 11 |
| 2018-09-12T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   5 | 12 |
| 2018-09-13T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   6 | 13 |
| 2018-09-14T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   0 | 14 |
| 2018-09-15T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   1 | 15 |
| 2018-09-16T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   2 | 16 |
| 2018-09-17T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   3 | 17 |
| 2018-09-18T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   4 | 18 |
| 2018-09-19T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   5 | 19 |
| 2018-09-20T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   6 | 20 |
| 2018-09-21T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   0 | 21 |
| 2018-09-22T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   1 | 22 |
| 2018-09-23T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   2 | 23 |
| 2018-09-24T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   3 | 24 |
| 2018-09-25T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   4 | 25 |
| 2018-09-26T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   5 | 26 |
| 2018-09-27T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   6 | 27 |
| 2018-09-28T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   0 | 28 |
| 2018-09-29T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   1 | 29 |
| 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   2 | 30 |
```

then we can try to use `rn - grp` to get the group, which is continuous.

**[Results]**:

```
|         StartOfMonth |           EndOfMonth | grp |
|----------------------|----------------------|-----|
| 2018-09-01T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   0 |
| 2018-09-02T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   0 |
| 2018-09-03T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   0 |
| 2018-09-04T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   0 |
| 2018-09-05T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   0 |
| 2018-09-06T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   0 |
| 2018-09-07T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   7 |
| 2018-09-08T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   7 |
| 2018-09-09T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   7 |
| 2018-09-10T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   7 |
| 2018-09-11T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   7 |
| 2018-09-12T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   7 |
| 2018-09-13T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |   7 |
| 2018-09-14T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |  14 |
| 2018-09-15T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |  14 |
| 2018-09-16T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |  14 |
| 2018-09-17T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |  14 |
| 2018-09-18T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |  14 |
| 2018-09-19T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |  14 |
| 2018-09-20T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |  14 |
| 2018-09-21T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |  21 |
| 2018-09-22T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |  21 |
| 2018-09-23T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |  21 |
| 2018-09-24T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |  21 |
| 2018-09-25T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |  21 |
| 2018-09-26T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |  21 |
| 2018-09-27T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |  21 |
| 2018-09-28T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |  28 |
| 2018-09-29T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |  28 |
| 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |  28 |
```

final, we just get all `count(*) = 7` group in month or year number, which mean complete weeks.

---

**Query 1**:

**full month**

```
;WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0) AS StartOfMonth,
         DATEADD(mm,1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0)) - 1  AS EndOfMonth
  UNION ALL
  SELECT StartOfMonth +1 , EndOfMonth
  FROM CTE 
  WHERE StartOfMonth < EndOfMonth
)
SELECT COUNT(*) fullweekAmount from (
  SELECT 
      MIN(StartOfMonth) startdt,
      MAX(StartOfMonth) enddt
  FROM (
    SELECT *,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY StartOfMonth) - 
          CASE DateName(DW, StartOfMonth)
              WHEN 'Friday' THEN 0
              WHEN 'Saturday' THEN 1
              WHEN 'Sunday' THEN 2
              WHEN 'Monday' THEN 3
              WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN 4
              WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN 5
              WHEN 'Thursday' THEN 6
              WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN 7 
          END grp
    FROM CTE
  ) t1
  GROUP BY grp
  having count(*) = 7
) t1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/32428/0)**:

```
| fullweekAmount |
|----------------|
|              3 |
```

---

**full year**

```
;WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT  DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS StartOfMonth,
          DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, -1)  - 1  AS EndOfMonth
  UNION ALL
  SELECT StartOfMonth +1 , EndOfMonth
  FROM CTE 
  WHERE StartOfMonth < EndOfMonth
)
SELECT COUNT(*) fullweekAmount from (
  SELECT 
      MIN(StartOfMonth) startdt,
      MAX(StartOfMonth) enddt
  FROM (
    SELECT *,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY StartOfMonth) - 
          CASE DateName(DW, StartOfMonth)
              WHEN 'Friday' THEN 0
              WHEN 'Saturday' THEN 1
              WHEN 'Sunday' THEN 2
              WHEN 'Monday' THEN 3
              WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN 4
              WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN 5
              WHEN 'Thursday' THEN 6
              WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN 7 
          END grp
    FROM CTE
  ) t1
  GROUP BY grp
  having count(*) = 7
) t1

option (maxrecursion 0)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d172cd89050221a9e20c616762062f24)

**Note**

if your *cte recursion* date more than 100 you will get the error

> The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

you can set

```
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

The `Case When` number `0` and `1` mean your weekoff day

Comment: As per your code, you said that, this month has `3 Friday- Thursday weeks`..!! Am I correct.??

Comment: can you please explain your eighth case, `WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN 7`..?

Comment: Yes but I am busy today, no time to write the full explain could you wait a moment. I am available tomorrow thanks.

Comment: The key word is Gaps and Islands problem

Comment: I am waiting. Okay I have no idea about `Gaps and Islands problem`. But I start learn about it.

Comment: @IdontKnowEnglish i add more explain :)

Comment: Thx @D-Shih Let me take some time to understand..!

Comment: @D-Shih we could solve this without taking into account the days between the start and end date..kindly look into my solution and provide feedback

Answer (score 2):

The alternative solution,

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE='20200722'--any valid date as your requirement needs(it is inclusive of the specified date)
DECLARE @MonthorYear CHAR='Y'--Valid inputs: 'M'->for month and 'Y'-> for year
DECLARE @WeekdayBeginning nVarchar(15)='Sunday'
----Valid inputs run the following query, in my case it is english, for you it may differ based on your language
--SELECT DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(d,-1,'20180903')) Union all
--SELECT DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(d,0,'20180903')) Union all
--SELECT DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(d,1,'20180903')) Union all
--SELECT DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(d,2,'20180903')) Union all
--SELECT DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(d,3,'20180903')) Union all
--SELECT DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(d,4,'20180903')) Union all
--SELECT DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(d,5,'20180903')) 


DECLARE @week TABLE
(ID int identity(0,1),DoW nVarchar(15),isWeekstart bit default 0)

INSERT INTO @week (DoW)
SELECT DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(d,-1,'20180903')) Union all
SELECT DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(d,0,'20180903')) Union all
SELECT DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(d,1,'20180903')) Union all
SELECT DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(d,2,'20180903')) Union all
SELECT DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(d,3,'20180903')) Union all
SELECT DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(d,4,'20180903')) Union all
SELECT DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(d,5,'20180903')) 

-- input validations
if not exists (SELECT 1 FROM @week where  DoW=@WeekdayBeginning)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Invalid @WeekdayBeginning input'
    RETURN
END 
if (@MonthorYear NOT IN ('M','Y'))
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Invalid @MonthorYear input'
    RETURN
END 

--Start of find logic
DECLARE @EndDate date
DECLARE @DaysMissed tinyint,@TempDays smallint,@Weeks tinyint

SELECT  @EndDate=
    case @MonthorYear WHEN 'M' THEN EOMONTH(@StartDate)
    ELSE DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@StartDate),12,31) END

UPDATE @week set isWeekstart=1 where Dow=@WeekdayBeginning
SELECT @TempDays=DATEDIFF(d,@StartDate,@EndDate)+1

if not exists(SELECT 1 FROM @week WHERE DATENAME(dw,@StartDate)=DoW and isWeekstart=1)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tempID tinyint,@WeekstartID tinyint
    SELECT @tempID=ID from @week WHERE DATENAME(dw,@StartDate)=DoW
    SELECT @WeekstartID=ID from @week WHERE isWeekstart=1
    WHILE(@WeekstartID<>@tempID)
    BEGIN
        SET @TempDays=@TempDays-1
        SET @tempID=@tempID+1
        if(@tempID>6)
        BEGIN
            SET @tempID=0
        END
    END
END
SET @Weeks=@TempDays/7
SELECT @Weeks as 'CompleteWeeks'
```

Comment: This solution gives the count of weeks with simple math operations and  max iteration of 6 rounds